# How to transmit data with ZIGBEE using visual studio c++

Tags: c++

HELP:How to transmit data with ZIGBEE using visual studio c++

Two xbee series 2:
XBEE 1-connected to a pc(which transmits data to my other xbee)
XBEE 2-receives data;connected to a LCD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: xbee 1 connected to a PC using rs232.

Answer (score 1):

To work with XBee connected on your pc you need:

- to install a driver from DIGI in order to plug your USB cable on the PC and on a socket with the XBee Mounted on (see (http://www.digi.com/support/supporttype?type=drivers) )
- then you use serial interface programming in C++

Answer (score 0):

```
void XBee::XBeeOpen(String^ PortCom)
{
    // very short exemple of in a XBee Class 
    try
    {
        SerialLink->PortName = PortCom;
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
     .....
    }

    SerialLink->BaudRate = 115200;
    SerialLink->Parity = Parity::None;
    SerialLink->StopBits = StopBits::One;
    SerialLink->DataBits = 8;
    SerialLink->Handshake = Handshake::None;

    // Set the read/write timeouts
    //    SerialLink->ReadTimeout = SerialPort::InfiniteTimeout;
    //    SerialLink->WriteTimeout = SerialPort::InfiniteTimeout;
    SerialLink->ReadTimeout = 20;
    SerialLink->WriteTimeout = 20;

    // Encoding
    SerialLink->Encoding = System::Text::Encoding::GetEncoding(28591);

    if ( !SerialLink->IsOpen )
        SerialLink->Open();

    SerialLink->BreakState = false;
    SerialLink->DiscardNull = false;

    Opened = SerialLink->IsOpen;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void    XBee::XBeeClose(void)
{
    if (SerialLink->IsOpen )
        SerialLink->Close();
    Opened = SerialLink->IsOpen;
}
```